# layout_below in custom adapter in listview

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

I make a custom `adapter` for `listview` but it not working, two `textview` are overlay when i build, but it worked when i make the xml, i used `layout_below`.
[image]

the string "nguyen quoc bao" and "13530" are overlay
**in xml**:
[image]

my `xml` code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_stud_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="111"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_stud_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView_stud_name"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:text="111"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_absence"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:text="Absence" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_check"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/btn_absence"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="@color/green"
        android:text="Check" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

How to resolve this? thanks for response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paste this layout as it is, This kind of design give you more flexibility for future changes **(tip - Try to use Linear layout as possible as you can because relative layout may change his behavior too much at run time )**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/llButtons"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_stud_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:text="111"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_stud_id"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView_stud_name"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:text="111"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

        </LinearLayout>   

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llButtons"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_absence"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:background="@color/red"
                android:text="Absence" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_check"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/btn_absence"
                android:background="@color/green"
                android:text="Check" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: thanks for help, but if i want to continue my first way, how to solve it?

Comment: you have to maintain too much of relation ship of view .....like this view left of this view , this view right of this , below this , above this ......that going to more hectic and not maintain his shape

Answer (score 1):

Remove **[layout_centerVertical](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_centerVertical)** property from Second **TextView**.

> If true, centers this child vertically within its parent.

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_stud_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="111"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_stud_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView_stud_name"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:text="111"/>
```

Comment: it moved to below but still overlap, i think because of the margin/padding

Comment: @HoàngĐăng for better way ,Use LinearLayout & add `android:layout_weight`

Comment: @HoàngĐăng If you will facing problem let me inform .